# Installed PyQt5 and Python, and put the address into Path but why isn't it working on PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, pyqt5

I have PyCharm and Python 3.10.2 installed, and I'm trying to get PyQt5 to work on PyCharm but I get an error that says

> No module named 'PyQt5'.

I checked on Command Prompt with 'pip install pyqt5'
and this is what I got:

> Requirement already satisfied: pyqt5 in c:\users\wsup2\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (5.15.6)
> Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5-sip<13,>=12.8 in c:\users\wsup2\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pyqt5) (12.10.1)
> Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5-Qt5>=5.15.2 in c:\users\wsup2\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pyqt5) (5.15.2)

So I added the above address to Path.

and I tried:

```
pip3 show PyQt5
```

and I got:

```
Name: PyQt5
Version: 5.15.6
Summary: Python bindings for the Qt cross platform application toolkit
Home-page: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/
Author: Riverbank Computing Limited
Author-email: info@riverbankcomputing.com
License: GPL v3
Location: c:\users\wsup2\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages
Requires: PyQt5-Qt5, PyQt5-sip
Required-by:
```

And that's where I'm not sure what else I'm supposed to do to make it work on PyCharm.

Please help.

Comment: @alexpdev I think it worked.! I installed it into the Pycharms build-in terminal. THANK YOU THANK YOU you have No idea how many days I've been struggling to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: Sure thing,  Ill post it as an answer so you can mark this as complete.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because Pycharm by default starts new projects in a virtual environment.

Try running the same install command inside the terminal that is built into Pycharm.

```
pip3 install PyQt5
```